# Prevent GTM custom tags from firing on certain pages in an SPA?

Tags: google-tag-manager

We have an SPA and third-party clients that can use GTM to add custom tags (HTML + Javascript) that will execute in our application. Being an SPA, all the GTM scripts are loaded on first load of the application, so the scrips run immediately. We want to be able to blacklist those script from running on certain pages. How do we do this?

Note: This is an important feature that is needed from GTM, in so far as PCI v4 compliance is looking to prevent the use of any non-PCI compliant Javascript on payment pages. We want to still be able to allow GTM for  analytics, but we want to specifically close off the option for our third-party to inject custom tags.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots or code examples of your current triggers and tags in GTM? Custom HTML tags don't just run on load unless you tell it to.

Comment: As GTM is in the control of third-party clients, I cannot provide this information.